# need help on the months section i have done the first part

Tags: java

This exercise is to write and test a Java application in which the main method class is called `SeasonClassification`. In addition to the main method, this class contains two `static` methods with the following headers:

```
public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day)
public static String findSeason(int month, int day)
```

To represent a valid date a pair of integers, month and day, must satisfy 1 ≤ month ≤ 12 and 1 ≤ day ≤ the number of days in the month. Given a pair of integers, month and day, `findSeason` is to return the corresponding season as
specified in the following table if the pair represents a valid date, and `"invalidDate”` otherwise.

```
date season
December 21 - March 20 Winter
March 21 - June 20 Spring
June 21 - September 20 Summer
September 21 - December 20 Autumn
```

THIS IS WHAT IVE DONE:

package javaapplication4;

public class JavaApplication4 {

```
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int month = 7;
        int date = 20;
        boolean check = isValidDate(month, date);
        System.out.println(check);
    }

    public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day) {
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
            if (day < 32) {
                return true;
            }
        if (month == 4||month == 6 || month == 9|| month ==11 )
            if(day < 31)
            return true;
       if (month== 2) 
           if(day < 29)
        }
        return false;
    }
    {
   public static String findSeason(int month, int day) {
        return "invalid date";
        switch:(month) {

           case 1: // january same season
           case 2: // february
               return "winter";
           case 3: // march
// season changes
           return (day <= 20? "winter" : "spring");
           case 4:// april
           case 5: //may
               return "spring";
            case 6: // june 
//season changes
           return (day <=20? "spring" : "summer");
           case 7: // july
           case 8: // august
               return"autumn";
           case 9: // september
           return (day <=20? "summer" : "autumn");
           case 10: // october
           case 11: // november
           return (day <=20? "autumn" : "winter");
           case 12: //december
    }
   return "invalidDate";}
```

}

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: please add it the question with the code format...

Comment: not sure how to do that sorry

Comment: @SamatarJibril There is an [edit] button under your question.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: what the error you getting?

Answer (score 0):

found a few problem with your code and the logic. should work now, but test different inputs to make sure

```
   public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day) {
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
            if (day > 0) {
                if (day < 32) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
                    if (day < 31)
                        return true;
                if (month == 2)
                    if (day < 29)
                        return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String findSeason(int month, int day){
        if (!isValidDate(month, day))
            return "invalidDate";

        switch(month) {

        case 1: // january same season
        case 2: // february
            return "winter";
        case 3: // march
// season changes
            return (day <= 20 ? "winter" : "spring");
        case 4:// april
        case 5: //may
            return "spring";
        case 6: // june
//season changes
            return (day <= 20 ? "spring" : "summer");
        case 7: // july
        case 8: // august
            return "summer";
        case 9: // september
            return (day <= 20 ? "summer" : "autumn");
        case 10: // october
        case 11: // november
            return "autumn";
        case 12: //december
          return (day <= 20 ? "autumn" : "winter");
        default:
            return "invalidDate";
        }
    }
```